# Sharing settings on Accounts and Opps

Tags: force.com, security, sharing

Is there a way for users to see **all** the accounts for a Record type, but not allow them to see the opportunities UNLESS they are the opp owner, or if another condition is met?

I think the answer is no,  but not 100%.

Can you suggest some workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use criteria-based sharing at the account level to share all accounts of a record type to a specified group or role, leaving the Opportunity access at private. Assuming opportunities are set to OWD private, the users will only be able to access opportunities they own, are a member of the sales team of, or are a manager of a user that owns the opportunity.

Comment: So I'm confused, I thought that the opp would inherit what ever sharing settings that were on the account since the account is a parent.

Comment: No, opportunities are shared separately, despite the account being the parent. This allows users that share common accounts to keep their opportunities on that account private from each other. I recommend you play around with it, and you'll see what I'm talking about. Cases are also magical that way-- support can have cases visible to them without the other people that have access to the account seeing those same cases.